# Emacs. How remove duplicate lines that contain some text

Tags: emacs

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1

Suppose I has text:

111111111 aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbb

222222 3333333333 44444444

111111111 aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbb

111111111 aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbb

44444444 666666666 777777777777

111111111 aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbb

So I want to remove duplicate lines that contain **aaaaaaaa**.

Result must be this:

111111111 aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbb

222222 3333333333 44444444

44444444 666666666 777777777777

I  want to use built-in capabilities of Emacs (without write custom elisp script).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to remove *all* duplicate lines from the buffer (regardless of whether or not they contain "aaaaaaaa"), then use:

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `delete-duplicate-lines` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Note that your desired result includes the removal of *all* blank lines (rather than retaining one of them), so Emacs' result is different on that account.

---

If you want to remove all lines containing "aaaaaaaa" then use:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `flush-lines` <kbd>RET</kbd> `aaaaaaaa` <kbd>RET</kbd>

If you issue this with point after the first instance, then it won't remove that first instance.

---

If you want the behaviour of `delete-duplicate-lines` but restricted to acting only on lines containing "aaaaaaaa", then I don't know of a standard command for that (although it would be a relatively simple enhancement to `delete-duplicate-lines` to introduce such a feature).

Comment: `delete-duplicate-lines` seems not working if the cursor is at the end of the buffer

Comment: I can't replicate that issue -- it works fine for me with the cursor/point being at the end of the buffer.  Tested in Emacs 27.1.